# Mazer Bootstrap & Thymleaf

Tags: bootstrap-5

I am using [Mazer Bootstrap theme](https://zuramai.github.io/mazer/demo/index.html) in my Springboot project, So I've used Thyemleaf to separate menu code as a Layout and I am importing Layout in my new pages and everything works as expected.
Here the problem is, Menu highlight is not working it's always Dashboard page selected. I want to enable or highlight the page whichever page user selected.

Since I am using Thyemleaf layout In new pages I am unable to highlight the current page link in Menu. Any idea how can I fix this?